# How to pass multiple arguments to custom written Robot Framework Keyword?

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

Custom Keyword written in python 2.7:

```
@keyword("Update ${filename} with ${properties}")
def set_multiple_test_properties(self, filename, properties):
    for each in values.split(","):
        each = each.replace(" ", "")
        key, value = each.split("=")
        self.set_test_properties(filename, key, value)
```

When we send paremeters in a single line as shown below, its working as expected:

```
"Update sample.txt with "test.update=11,timeout=20,delay.seconds=10,maxUntouchedTime=10"
```

But when we modify the above line with a new lines (for better readability) it's not working.

```
Update sample.txt with "test.update = 11,
                        timeout=20,
                        delay.seconds=10,
                        maxUntouchedTime=10"
```

Any clue on this please?

Comment: are you asking about how to provide multiple arguments, or a long argument that has embedded newlines? Your question title and body seem to be asking two different questions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure whether it will work or not, but please try like this

```
Update sample.txt with "test.update = 11,
... timeout=20,
... delay.seconds=10,
... maxUntouchedTime=10"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Above method is not working. RFW is considering each line as a separate keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not working, cause the 2nd line is considered a call to a keyword (called "timeout=20,"), the 3rd another one, and so on. The 3 dots don't work cause they are "cell separators" - delimiter b/n arguments.

If you are going for readability, you can use the Catenate kw (it's in the Strings library):

```
${props}=    Catenate      SEPARATOR=${SPACE}
...     test.update = 11,
...     timeout=20,
...     delay.seconds=10,
...     maxUntouchedTime=10
```

, and then call your keyword with that variable:

```
Update sample.txt with "${props}"
```

---

btw, a) I think your keyword declaration in the decorator is without the double quotes - i.e. called like that ^ they'll be treated as part of the argument's value, b) there seems to be an error in the py method - the argument's name is "properties" while the itterator uses "values", and c) you might want to consider using named varargs (**kwargs in python, ${kwargs} in RF syntax) for this purpose (sorry, offtopic, but couldn't resist :)